# Summation for $\sum\limits^5_{i=2}\:\left(3i\:-\:5\right)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation

I know that the closed form of $\sum\limits^n_{k=1}\:k=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$

But I'm not sure what the closed form for $\sum\limits^5_{i=2}\:\left(3i\:-\:5\right)$ would be.

Any push in the right direction would be helpful.

Comment: Do you understand what summation means? You are only given 4 instances of this summation to calculate? Just apply the definition of summation and find the answer to this when $i = \{2,3,4,5\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\sum^5_{i=2} \left(3i - 5\right)
&=
\sum_{i=2}^5 3i - \sum_{i=2}^5 5 \\
&=
3 \sum_{i=2}^5 i - 5 \sum_{i=2}^5 1 \\
&=
3 \left(-1 + \sum_{i=1}^5 i \right) - 5 \sum_{i=1}^4 1 \\
&=
3 \left(
\frac{5\cdot 6}{2} - 1
\right)
- 5 \cdot 4
\\
&= 
3 \cdot 14 - 20 \\
&= 22
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

There are two closed form for the two finites series above:

$$\sum_{k = 2}^{N} 3k = \frac{3}{2}(N^2 + N - 2)$$

$$\sum_{k = 2}^{N} 5 = 5(N-1)$$

Thence in your case

$$\sum_{k = 2}^{5} 3k = \frac{3}{2}(5^2 + 5 - 2) = 42$$

$$\sum_{k = 2}^{5} 5 = 5(5-1) = 20$$

Thence

$$S = 42 - 20 = 22$$

Answer (score -1):

$\sum\limits^5_{i=2}(3i-5)=\sum\limits^5_{i=2}3i-\sum\limits_{i=2}^5 5$

$\sum\limits^5_{i=2}3i=3(2)+3(3)+3(4)+3(5)$

$\sum\limits_{i=2}^5 5=5+5+5+5$

Comment: Anyone care to explain the downvote?

Comment: I did not vote on your answer -- but why use the détour of decomposing the sum to be computed into the sum of two sums instead of working directly with 1+4+7+10, easily computed as 5+7+10, that is, 12+10, that is, 22? Personally, I would rather enquire about the reason for the 2 upvotes...

Comment: The detour was a personal choice. Apparently, 2 people found it useful, one of whom is the questioner.

Comment: Interesting. Perhaps your comment asking for explanations about the downvote was not to be taken seriously then.